# "The system cannot find the file specified" when invoking subprocess.Popen in python

Tags: python, svn-merge

I'm trying to use `svnmerge.py` to merge some files. Under the hood it uses python, and when I use it I get an error - "The system cannot find the file specified". Colleagues at work are running the same version of `svnmerge.py`, and of python (2.5.2, specifically r252:60911) without an issue.

I found [this link](http://www.nabble.com/problem-under-some-windows-desktop-td15868057.html), which describes my problem. Trying what was outlined there, I confirmed Python could find SVN (it's in my path):

```
P:\>python
Python 2.5.2 (r252:60911, Feb 21 2008, 13:11:45) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> i,k = os.popen4("svn --version")
>>> i.close()
>>> k.readline()
'svn, version 1.4.2 (r22196)\n'
```

Looking at the `svnmerge.py` code, though, I noticed for python versions 2.4 and higher it was following a different execution path. Rather than invoking
os.popen4() it uses subprocess.Popen(). Trying that reproduces the error:

```
C:\>python
Python 2.5.2 (r252:60911, Feb 21 2008, 13:11:45) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)] on win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> p = subprocess.Popen("svn --version", stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
>>> close_fds=False, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:\Python25\lib\subprocess.py", line 594, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python25\lib\subprocess.py", line 816, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
>>>
```

For now, I've commented out the 2.4-and-higher specific code, but I'd like to find a proper solution.

If it's not obvious, I'm a complete python newbie, but Google hasn't helped.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's a bug, see the [documentation of `subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/lib/node528.html). There either needs to be a `"shell=True`" option, or the first argument needs to be a sequence `['svn', '--version']`. As it is now, `Popen` is looking for an executable named, literally, "svn --version" which it doesn't find.

I don't know why it would work for your colleagues though, if they are running the same OS and version of Python... FWIW it gives me the same error message on a mac, and either of the two ways I gave fixes it.

Comment: can you please show the syntax for where you write `shell=true`

Comment: I actually found it `subprocess.run(["svn", "--version"], shell=True)`