# Tabula - Read the PDF's table content

Tags: python, tabula

While reading the PDF content, I got the below error.

File "PDF_Conversion.py", line 4, in 
    df = tabula.read_pdf("new_20170630.pdf")

> File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 672, in **init**
>       errread, errwrite)   File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 882, in _execute_child
>       startupinfo) WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["The system cannot find the file specified" when invoking subprocess.Popen in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36324/the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-when-invoking-subprocess-popen-in-py)

Comment: In which directory are you trying to find the mentioned file?

Comment: Using tabula to get the table data from PDF. When i use the "tabula.read_pdf"  It will raise the above mentioned error